# Passing a variable to other dialog Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qtgui, qdialog

I have a `QTreeView` with a list of text files. If a file is selected and `void FileList_dialog::on_openButton_released()` it should pass a variable `path`to dialog `textFile_dialog`.

Until now I've this:

```
void FileList::on_openButton_released()
{
    QModelIndex index = ui->treeView->currentIndex();
    QFileSystemModel *model = (QFileSystemModel*)ui->treeView->model();
    QString path = model->filePath(index);
    QString name = model->fileName(index);
    QString dir = path;
    QFile file(path);
    qDebug() << path;

    textFile_dialog textFile;
    textFile.setModal(true);
    textFile.exec();
}
```

But how do I pass the variable `path` to `textFile_dialog`?

Comment: Aside: It is redundant to explicitly set the dialog to modal. `QDialog::exec()` does this anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have have several options:

1) Pass the path to the dialog constructor

The code would look something like this:

#### textfile_dialog.h

```
class TextFile_Dialog : public QDialog 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit TextFile_Dialog(const QString &path, QObject *parent = 0);
    ...
    private:
        QString m_path;
};
```

#### textfile_dialog.cpp

```
...

#include "textfile_dialog.h"

...

TextFile_Dialog::TextFileDialog(const QString &path, QObject *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , m_path(path)
{
    ...
}

...
```

Then you would use the class like this:

```
textFile_dialog textFile_Dialog(path);
```

2) You could also have a setter method for setting the path as follows:

#### textfile_dialog.h

```
class TextFile_Dialog : public QDialog 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    ...
        void setPath(const QString &path);
    ...
    private:
        QString m_path;
};
```

#### textfile_dialog.cpp

```
...

#include "textfile_dialog.h"

...

void TextFile_Dialog::setPath(const QString &path)
{
    m_path = path;
}

...
```

Then the usage would be like this:

```
textFile_dialog textFile_Dialog;
textFile_Dialog.setPath(path);
```

Comment: I tried both options, but get an error, `'path' was not declared in this scope` in textFile_dialog.cpp (I used path in a function)

Comment: That last part with `"Then the usage would be like this: ..."`. I'm supposed to use that in **FileList_dialog.cpp** right? Not in **textFile_dialog.cpp**

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg: yes, so "path" is not declared means that you did something wrong, because it is declared here: QString path = model->filePath(index);

Comment: Oh, at option 1: `error: only declarations of constructors can be 'explicit'`

Comment: Nope, I did it in a other way, without a new dialog. But thanks for the help. And as you said I'll learn more C++, usually I 'learn' by doing just random projects like this one.

Comment: Wow, I see my stupid mistake. And I'm sorry if I offended you. But my mistake was: I used `path` in all my functions instead of `m_path`.. Newbie mistake I guess. I'm sorry and thanks for helping.
[image](http://imgur.com/YsN5n4Z) :)

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg: ah, ok, nice.

Comment: I have tested and worked the first method( Passing value using constructor). It will working good. Thanks @Ipapp

Answer (score 0):

In the header of the textFile_dialog class, you add a parameter to the constructor:

```
explicit textFile_dialog(const QString &a_path);
```

and in the **FileList::on_openButton_released()** change the constructor call to:

```
textFile_dialog textFile(path);
```

Comment: I get an error :`error: undefined reference to textFile_dialog::textFile_dialog(QString const&)'`

Comment: Instead of adding the whole `explicit textFile_dialog(const QString &a_path);` add only the parameter to an already existing constructor declaration. And I think you get this error because you only changed the header file and forgot to apply the changes to the **.cpp** file too.

Comment: It now says: `"path" is not declared.` I think I'm doing something wrong in the .cpp file. What should I change in the .cpp file according to you? Should I add something here?: `textFile_dialog::textFile_dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::textFile_dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}`