# QT Passing parameter to QDialog requirements

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, qdialog

*please note : a c++ qt newbie here, be gentle*

I found an extremely helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948665/passing-a-variable-to-other-dialog-qt) regarding send information to a `QDialog`, but I have a concern regarding my own implementation.

Say one has a custom `QDialog = LoginStatusDialog`
Say one needs to pass `QString username, password` to `LoginStatusDialog` via its constructor as shown by my `loginstatusdialog.h`

```
class LoginStatusDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
//    explicit LoginStatusDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);   <<< --- ORIGINAL constuctor before adding parameters
    explicit LoginStatusDialog(QWidget *parent = 0, const QString &_login = NULL, const QString &_key = NULL);
...

private:
    Ui::LoginStatusDialog *ui;
    QString login, key;
};
```

Here I am required to 2 implement 2 changes that the mentioned post lacks:

```
1. `const` : I am required to define the parameter as a constant

2. `= NULL` : I am required to add a default value
```

Why are both of these required, where the post lacks these or were they just neglected as a given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need change you constructor like this:

```
LoginStatusDialog(const QString &_login, const QString &_key, QWidget *parent = 0);
```

With this you avoid adding default values to your parameters. Also you don't need declare constructor as `explicit`. It's make sence only for constructors with only one parameter to avoid implicit type casting.

Second, `const QString &` means you send value to method by reference. With this you avoid extra data copy. You don't required to do this. You can declare parameter just like `QString login`, but make so is not a good practice. For more information please refer to [this article](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).